# remove certain javascript from html

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to remove following javascript from html file.

```
<script src="text/javascript>
alert('hello');

})();

</script>
```

and

```
<script src="text/javascript>
alert('hello');
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

By reading http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-howto-remove-lines-paragraphs/ I can use:

```
sed '/<script type="text\/javascript"/,/<\/script>/d'
```

but it will remove all the javascript.

My specific requirement is javascript one ending with `})(); (new line)</script>` and other ending with `} catch(err) {}</script>`

I want to use sed, if not possible then any program similar to sed so that I can run it through script.

Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Its already loaded whats the point of removing it?

Comment: Did you intentionally omit the closing double quote on the `src` attributes, or was that a typo in the question?

Comment: this is just a sample question I created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` or a programming language of your choice

```
awk -vRS="</script>" '/<script/ { if(/}\)\(\);|catch\(err\)/) { gsub(/script.*/,"");}  }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/text\\/javascript/{:a;N;/<\/script>/!ba;s/.*})();\n\n<\/script>|.*} catch(err) {}<\/script>//}'
```

It will remove all the javascript blocks end with `})(); (new line)</script>` or `} catch(err) {}</script>`.

A little explaination:

- **/text/javascript/**: the block begins from a tag contains `text/javascript`
- **:a**: create a label
- **N**: read the next line to the pattern space
- **/<\script>/!ba**: if it's not the close tag, branch to the lable `a`
- **s/pattern//**:remove the pattern space if it satisfy the condition